# What is the equivalent of HTTP request using “curl … --data-binary string” in Go?

Tags: curl, go, net-http

for example the curl code:

```
curl "http://example.com" --data-binary $'abc\r\ndef' --compressed
```

how to translate it to Go code?

What I have try is:

```
body := []byte("abc\r\ndef")
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com", bytes.NewBuffer(body))
resp, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

Comment: Why do you think that what you've tried is not already what you are looking for? For me it does exactly the same as the curl cmdline you show: add the given payload without additional processing and also request a compressed response.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The missing bits are `--compressed`

Comment: @dolmen: to cite myself: *"... and also request a compressed response"*. So, nothing is missing since this is exactly what `--compressed` does.

Comment: I have solved this problem by this tool https://github.com/two/curl-to-go, fork from  https://github.com/mholt/curl-to-go